# Counting Eligible Employee that can Participate in a Course Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Suppose we have tables like below:

employee

| employee_id | position_name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | Staff | Bob |
| E2 | Staff | Bib |
| E3 | Manager | Bub |
| E4 | Manager | Bab |

courses

| course_id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | Basic A |
| C2 | Advance A |
| C3 | Expert A |
| C4 | General A |

employee_certificate

| employee_certificate_id | course_id | employee_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EC1 | C1 | E2 |
| EC2 | C2 | E2 |
| EC3 | C1 | E1 |

course_plan

| course_plan_id | course_id | position_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CP1 | C2 | Staff |
| CP2 | C3 | Manager |
| CP3 | C4 | Staff |

course_plan_requirement

| course_plan_requirement_id | course_id | certificate_course_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CPR1 | C3 | C1 |
| CPR2 | C3 | C2 |
| CPR3 | C2 | C1 |

Each employee can complete 0 to many courses and get certified which recorded in employee_certificate

Each course_plan can 0 to many course_plan requirement which recorded in course_plan_requirement

An Employee can participate in a course_plan if the employee meets the course_plan_requirement and have the corresponding position,
for example:
To participate in course_plan with course C3 an employee have to be a Manager and certified in course C1, and C1,

To participate in course_plan with course C4 an employee have to be a Staff and can participate even without having certified in any course,

as we can see from course_plan_requirement.

**The Objective is to calculate how many employees can participate in each course_plan.**

I have come up with this query

```
with
CPR as(
    select cp.course_id, cp.position_name, count(cpr.certificate_course_id) as RCount
    from course_plan cp
    left join course_plan_requirement cpr on cp.course_id = cpr.course_id
    group by cp.course_id, cp.position_name
),
ECR as(
    select e.employee_id, cp.course_id, e.position_name, COUNT(cpr.certificate_course_id) as RCount
    from course_plan cp 
    left join employee e on cp.position_name = e.position_name
    left join employee_certificate ec on e.employee_id = ec.employee_id
    left join course_plan_requirement cpr on ec.course_id = cpr.certificate_course_id
    group by e.employee_id, cp.course_id, e.position_name
),
CEC as(
    select e.employee_id, e.position_name, cpr.course_id, ecr.RCount as AC, cpr.RCount BC,
    case 
        when ecr.RCount is null and cpr.RCount is null then 1
        when ecr.RCount = cpr.RCount then 1 else 0
    end as Eligibility
    from CPR cpr
    left join employee e on cpr.position_name = e.position_name
    left join ECR ecr on e.employee_id = ecr.employee_id
),
EligibleEmployee as (
    select cec.position_name, cec.course_id, sum(cec.Eligibility) as EligibleMP
    from CEC cec
    group by cec.position_name, cec.course_id
)
select * 
from course_plan cp
left join EligibleEmployee ee on cp.course_id = ee.course_id and cp.position_name = ee.position_name
```

But this has performance issues in my real database it took a while to query.
I wonder if I'm missing something obvious that can simplify the query process.

I hope that I could get some help from SQL Server experts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per my understanding:

- Each course as one mandatory position
- Each course can have zero or more certificate requirement

You can take advantage of `OUTER JOIN` and `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` as follows:

```
SELECT
    CP.COURSE_PLAN_ID,
    E.EMPLOYEE_ID
  FROM
         COURSES C
      JOIN COURSE_PLAN             CP ON CP.COURSE_ID = C.COURSE_ID
      JOIN EMPLOYEE                E ON E.EPOSITION_NAME = CP.POSITION_NAME
      LEFT JOIN COURSE_PLAN_REQUIREMENT CPR ON CP.COURSE_ID = CPR.COURSE_ID
      LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_CERTIFICATE    EC ON EC.COURSE_ID = CPR.CERTIFICATION_COURSE_ID
       AND EC.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
 GROUP BY
    CP.COURSE_PLAN_ID,
    E.EMPLOYEE_ID
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT CPR.CERTIFICATE_COURSE_ID) = COUNT(DISTINCT EC.COURDSE_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks this opened a path to a better query.